# How do I find the maximum gain limit for a delayed system?

Tags: polynomials, optimization, roots, control-theory, optimal-control

Finding the maximum gain limit is very easy. Assume that we have a transfer function.

$$G(s) = \frac {num (s)}{den (s)} $$

If we want to compute the maximum gain limit when system $G (s) $ is implemented into a feedback system. We find the roots from.

$$0=Knum (s) + den (s) $$

Where $K $ is the gain limit.

But how would I do if my transfer function looked like this:

$$G(s) = \frac {num (s)}{den (s)}e^{-Ls} $$

Then I would have a feedback system and then to compute the maximum gain limit:

$$0=Knum (s)e^{-Ls}+ den (s) $$

The only problem is that $s $ is a complex number. How can I find the roots from that equation?

I have solver a nondelayed problem by using this code

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/matavecontrol/blob/master/sourcecode/findmaxgain.m

Can I solve this with Padé approximation or will this result a bad solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have time-delays and work in continuous time, you cannot analyze poles in the classical meaning. Instead, you can for instance do standard design and then analyze stability using phase margins, or you do design where you explicitly consider the delay using for instance a Smith predictor. Or as you indicate, use an approximation of the time-delay. Or go to discrete-time and do the design there.

Concering your code for analyzing stability when tweaking a gain, it looks like you should take a look at the very standard theory of root-loci analysis (rotort in Swedish). It can be found in essentially any introductory course/text on control. The command is rlocus in MATLAB

Comment: Do you think padé approximation will solve this?

Comment: Depends on the size of the time-delay relative to the dynamics. If severe enough, you have to deal with it explicitly such as with a Smith predictor. If small enough, it just about having a sufficiently large phase margin.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will do time delay approximation by Padé. I can do time discrete state space models, but the matrices will be very large.